# powershell Insert text between foreach loop

Tags: powershell, separator

I need to get `-and` between every foreach loop result to create a array. It means that I can not have it at the end of the array!

My script is like this:

```
Param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
[string]$IncludeFilesCSVPath = "\\mypath\IncludeFiles.csv"
)

$includeFilesCsv = Import-CSV $IncludeFilesCSVPath


$includeFilesList = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.Generic.List[string]"
foreach ($item in $includeFilesCsv) {
    $includeFilesList.Add('(-not (Attachment -like "*' + $item.Godkjent + '"))')
}
$includeFiles = $includeFilesList.ToArray()

Write-Host $IncludeFiles
```

The CSV file has headers: `Godkjent`
And each line contains file endings like `.EXE .TXT .PS1`

The output is now:

`(-not (Attachment -like "*.DOC")) (-not (Attachment -like "*.DOCX")) (-not (Attachment -like "*.TXT")) (-not (Attachment -like "*.CSV"))`

But i need:

`(-not (Attachment -like "*.DOC")) -and (-not (Attachment -like "*.DOCX")) -and (-not (Attachment -like "*.TXT")) -and (-not (Attachment -like "*.CSV"))`

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to collect the `foreach` item output *explicitly* in a list - using the statement as a whole as an expression *implicitly* returns the outputs as an *array*.
- To piece the elements of an array together with a separator in order to form a single string, use the `-join` operator.

```
$includeFiles = $(foreach ($item in $includeFilesCsv) {
  '(-not (Attachment -like "*' + $item.Godkjent + '"))'
}) -join ' -and '
```

Note the need for `$(...)` around the `foreach` loop to make it part of a larger expression. (`@(...)`, to guarantee an array, would work here too, but it makes no effective difference).

<sup>The perhaps surprising need for `$(...)` rather than just `(...)` is discussed in [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6817).</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
Param (
[Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]
[string]$IncludeFilesCSVPath = "\\mypath\IncludeFiles.csv"
)

$includeFilesCsv = Import-CSV $IncludeFilesCSVPath

$Total = $includeFilesCsv.count
$counter = 0
$includeFilesList = New-Object -TypeName "System.Collections.Generic.List[string]"

foreach ($item in $includeFilesCsv) {

    $counter++

    if ($counter -ne $Total) {
        $includeFilesList.Add('(-not (Attachment -like "*' + $item.Godkjent + '")) -and')
    } 
    else {
        $includeFilesList.Add('(-not (Attachment -like "*' + $item.Godkjent + '"))')
    }

}

$includeFiles = $includeFilesList.ToArray()

Write-Host $IncludeFiles
```

This how my CSV file looks like:

[image]

This my output from the above script:
[image]

Let me know if it doesn't work. I will try again.